# XmlDeserialization fails in medium trust level

Tags: xml-deserialization, medium-trust

We have our site hosted in medium trust level and the hosting provider has refused to give us full trust. Our code tries to deserialize code using following code snippet but fails with the reflectionpermission error. Upon debug I get "There is an error in XML document (71, 6)." error. It works perfectly fine in full trust. Please someone advice how I can solve this problem before we decide to move to full trust hosting provider.

```
    public static T Decrypt<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        Rijndael rij = Rijndael.Create();
        rij.Key = key;
        rij.IV = iv;
        T obj = default(T); // assigns null if T is a reference type, or 0 (zero) for value types

        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, rij.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (GZipStream zs = new GZipStream(cs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                obj = (T)xs.Deserialize(zs);

                zs.Close();
            }
            cs.Close();
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the project properties and set "Generate serialization assembly" to "on".  This will make the compiler generate serialization assemblies at compile-time instead of on the fly.  Just make sure to deploy the serialization assemblies.

Comment: I tried your recommendation to the project and all dependent projects but did not seems to work. Still receiving same error.